# Using negative numbers with sed

Tags: regex, sed

When using `sed`, I can use `[0-9]` to match any number. However, this seems to only look for positive numbers. How can I have it also look for numbers beginning with `-`, for e.g.: `-10`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[0-9]` does not match the numbers 0 through 9.  It matches the characters 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, and 9.

To have it require that a `-` character precede it, just put it in there, escaped with a backslash so it doesn't have its usual special meaning in a regexp.  So `\-[1-9]` will match the strings -1, -2, etc. up to -9.

If you want it to match any negative number, use:

```
\-[0-9]+
```

(The `+` means "one or more occurrences of the previous thing" so in this case "one or more digits".)

If you want it to match any negative or positive number, use:

```
\-?[0-9]+
```

(The `?` means "one or zero occurrences of the previous thing" so here it means "a - or nothing".)

**UPDATE**

@Jonathan Leffler points out that the above will not work if your version of `sed` does not support extended regular expressions.  If they don't work, use these instead:

```
\-[0-9]\{1,\}
\-\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}
```

Also, Jonathan's answer also includes this, which will match a leading `+` too--not requested in the question, but a good touch for sure:

```
[-+]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}
```

Comment: By default, standard versions of `sed` use BRE (basic regular expression) syntax and not ERE (extended regular expression) syntax.  The `+` and `?` don't work; you have to write `\{1,\}` or `\{0,1\}` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
\-?[0-9]+
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex `[0-9]` matches any single decimal digit.

To match an optionally signed decimal integer in `sed`, use:

```
[-+]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}
```

The `\{0,1\}` means match 0 or 1 occurrence of the preceding regex (which is either a `-` or a `+`), followed by `\{1,\}` (one or more) digits `[0-9]`.